# How to check ResultSet for emptiness inside Spring JDBC ResultSetExtractor?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, java-8

It seems that standard check of `ResultSet` emptiness will not work in Spring's JDBC `ResultSetExtractor`. I use it in following way:

```
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, ps -> {
        ps.setLong(1, fooParam1);
        ps.setLong(2, fooParam2);
    }, rs -> {
        return rs.getLong(1);
    });
```

So what is the correct way check `ResultSet` emptiness in such pattern?

Comment: Why don't you use rs.hasNext()?

Comment: @RadhakrishnaSharmaGorenta there isn't such method in `ResultSet` class

Comment: Of course, it is possible that your first parameter `sql` is a `PreparedStatementCreator` implementation that does already invoke `next()`, but you can’t blame me, when you are using something contradicting to the API without posting the code in your question. You can try your setup with one of the `query` overloads that return a `List`. Is the first row included or missing? As already proven, Springs own `ResultSetExtractor` implementations *do* call `next()`.

Comment: You wording suggests that the “synthetic” nature of the `ResultSet` makes a difference. That would be a quite dangerous setup. As already emphasized multiple times, [Springs own `ResultSetExtractor` implementations](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.jdbc/3.2.5/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java#88) will invoke `next()` and if you managed to get an environment, where that doesn’t work correctly, you should rethink that. You solution may work in that setup, but that’s not helpful to other users then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There seems to be some confusion about the roles of the interfaces, I saw some tutorials doing it wrong. The interfaces `RowMapper` and `RowCallbackHandler` are responsible for providing a value, resp. producing a side effect, per row.

Therefore, they are not responsible for invoking `next()` as the framework will take care of advancing to the next row and not invoking the callback, once `next()` returned `false` which may happen even when advancing to the first row, in which case the `ResultSet` is empty. In the latter case, [`query(… RowMapper<T>)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.0.RC2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-) will return an empty `List` without invoking the `RowMapper` and [`query(… RowCallbackHandler)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.0.RC2/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object:A-int:A-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowCallbackHandler-) will simply do nothing.

In contrast, [`ResultSetExtractor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.3.0.RC2/javadoc-api/?org/springframework/jdbc/core/ResultSetExtractor.html) is responsible for processing *the entire* `ResultSet`, which includes invoking `next()` appropriately. So your question’s premise (“… each call of `extractData` gives me new row.”) is wrong. The standard behavior of all JDBC operations is to return a `ResultSet` being before the first row so that the first `next()` invocation will either move the current row pointer to the first row or return `false` if the `ResultSet` is empty. So if you expect at most one row, your query should rather look like

```
return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, ps -> {
        ps.setLong(1, fooParam1);
        ps.setLong(2, fooParam2);
   }, rs -> rs.next()? rs.getLong(1): null);
```

**EDIT:** This solution tested and works correctly on standard `MySQL` and `Postgresql` instances /*Andremoniy*/.

**EDIT-2:** This solution absolutely correct and works correctly anywhere. But it should be **noticed** that there are two different methods in `JdbcTemplate` class:

1. `public <T> T query(String sql, PreparedStatementSetter pss, ResultSetExtractor<T> rse)`  - it is used in this example and it returns `0` for `rs.getRows()` always, indeed. Provided solution is correct for this case.
2. `public void query(String sql, PreparedStatementSetter pss, RowCallbackHandler rch)` which has another type of 3rd parameter, and similar code:

   `jdbcTemplate.query(sql, ps -> {
       ps.setLong(1, fooParam1);
       ps.setLong(2, fooParam2);
   }, rs -> {
       System.out.println(rs.getRow());
   });`

will work differently: `rs.getRow()` will return number of processing row, and if no rows exist, `processRow` method will be never invoked (this second method caused my confusing). /*Andremoniy*/

Comment: excuse me, but I can not agree with you. `ResultSetExractor` gives me `extractData` each time new `ResultSet` object, so it calls `next` somewhere internally. Furthermore, if you call `next()` inside `extractData()` several times, you will move advance and will broke processing of entire queue result. In respect to your rating I will not downvote your answer, but it looks like incorrect, sorry

Comment: Of course it provides you a **new** `ResultSet` each time. How does that prove that `next()` has been called on that `ResultSet`? It actually proves what I said, this callback is responsible for *processing the entire result set* as next time it gets called, it will receive a new one.

Comment: Apparently you are confusing *rows* and `RowSet`. A `RowSet` can have an arbitrary number of rows and while a `RowMapper` is invoked *once for each row*, in other words, gets a new **row** on each call, a `ResultSetExtractor` is not. The `ResultSetExtractor` is invoked *once per result*, represented by a fresh `ResultSet`. Since each call represents an entirely new query, it doesn’t matter how often (or whether) you invoked `next()` on the previous query’s `ResultSet` (which has been closed in the meanwhile).

Comment: @Andremoniy: then *why* do you think you can not invoke `next()` on the `ResultSet`?

Comment: *Why* I can not invoke `rs.getRow()` in same case?

Comment: Because the initial state of the `ResultSet` is *always* before the first row. You will always get `0`, unless you invoke `next()` at least once. Did you look at [the code, I already linked](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.jdbc/3.2.5/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java#88)? Notice how `next()` is invoked *before* the first row is read. Besides that, `getRow` is not supported by all `ResultSet`s.

Comment: @Andremoniy And have you read the JDBC api doc for [`ResultSet.getRow()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow--) _" Note:Support for the getRow method is optional for ResultSets with a result set type of TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY"_ and _"SQLFeatureNotSupportedException - if the JDBC driver does not support this method"_

Comment: @MarkRotteveel And what? Have I use this type? Does `JdbcTemplate` use it in `query` method? What's problem?

Comment: @Andremoniy: that’s the whole point, “Does `JdbcTemplate` use it in `query` method?” You don’t know, as `JdbcTemplate` does not fix the type of the result set, but abstracts the entire thing. So it *could* use it, depending on the actual `PreparedStatementCreator` in use. But you are still ignoring the point that the current row is zero anyway, unless you invoke `next()` at least once.

Comment: I’m not going to install MySQL for that. The [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.springframework/org.springframework.jdbc/3.2.5/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#639) consists of 20 lines and it’s easy to see that there is no one calling `next()` before the `ResultSetExtractor` receives the `ResultSet`. Unless you have modified the environment in a way, not specified in your question.

Comment: @Andremoniy I'm not sure where your disagreement with this answer is coming from. Holger is correct in saying that a `ResultSetExtractor` should process the _whole_ ResultSet, which means calling `next()` itself to loop over the results. If you compare with `query(..., ..., RowCallbackHandler)`, you'll notice that [it creates](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java/#736) a `RowCallbackHandlerResultSetExtractor` which loops over the results with `while (rs.next()) {`.

Comment: @Andremoniy This is link to [the soure code of that while loop](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring-jdbc/4.2.0.RELEASE/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.java#1565). This is expected since a `RowCallbackHandler` is called for each row of the results (i.e. Spring handle the calls to `next()` in this case and invokes your `processRow` on each row). Contrary to a `ResultSetExtractor`, which is supposed to extract all of the results itself.

Comment: @Tunaki, I've made check of this solution. Incorrectness caused by the fact, that invocation of `rs.next()` leads to moving to next row, while current row will be skipped. So this is just incorrect usage of `rs.next()` for `ResultSetExtractor`.

Comment: @Holger I have to ask you excuse me. It appears to be bug in `mysql` instance, because on `postgresql` and standard `mysql` instances it works correctly, while my solution - not. I'm going to test it more detailed and create appropriate ticket for that. Essentially it appears, that your solution will not work in my particular environment. My apologies  again. I have to slightly edit your answer in order to delete downvote.

Comment: @Tunaki, Holger, I was confused about two similar methods `T query(...)` and `void query(...)`. They work differently, and last one indeed returns number of row inside `rs.getRow()`, but it doesn't matter. My great apologies.

Comment: @Andremoniy: regarding the overloads, I think they are indeed unfortunate. But that’s why I emphasized in an earlier comment the “shape of the lambda expression”, which is sufficient here to disambiguate. A single argument lambda which returns a value (and is not `void` compatible) can only be a `ResultSetExtractor`. This can be quite subtle, i.e. in your question you are using `rs -> { return rs.getLong(1); }` which is unambiguous, but when you simplify it to `rs -> rs.getLong(1)`, it can be `void` compatible, dropping the result, thus, could be a `RowCallbackHandler` as well.